# Nested decorators with arguments in Python - call stack

Tags: python, python-decorators

I am reading about Python decorators and I have stumbled upon example of nested decorators with arguments.
I have tried to understand its call stack, but some steps seems to have no logic for me. Could someone please break down this call stack into little pieces for me?

```
from datetime import datetime


def log_before_and_after(func):
    def wrapper():
        print("log_before_and_after_wrapper start")
        result = func()
        print("log_before_and_after_wrapper end")
        return result

    return wrapper


def run_only_between(_from=7, _to=22):
    print("run_only_between start")

    def real_decorator(func):
        print("real_decorator start")

        def wrapper():
            print("run_only_between_wrapper start")
            if _from <= datetime.now().hour < _to:
                func()
                print("run_only_between_wrapper end")
            else:
                print("run_only_between_wrapper end")

        print("real_decorator end")
        return wrapper

    print("run_only_between end")
    return real_decorator


@log_before_and_after
@run_only_between(7, 22)
def say_something():
    print("Hello!!")


say_something()  # <---
```

and the output is:

```
run_only_between start
run_only_between end
real_decorator start
real_decorator end
log_before_and_after_wrapper start
run_only_between_wrapper start
Hello!!
run_only_between_wrapper end
log_before_and_after_wrapper end
```

My questions are:
Why after `"real_decorator end"` print,  `"log_before_and_after_wrapper start"` print is executed?

Why `run_only_between wrapper` is called next?

Why then exexution goes back to the `log_before_and_after_wrapper`

I would be grateful for any help here.

EDIT:
[Debug order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJ15M.png)

Why after returning `wrapper` in `real_decorator` code jumps to `@run_only_between` and than to `log_before_and_after()`? Shouldn't `wrapper()` be executed since it was returned by `real_decorator`?

Why after returning `wrapper` in `log_before_and_after`, `say_something()` is beeing executed and only after that code returns to `wrapper` in `log_before_and_after`?

Comment: I think you'd have an easier time if you run your code in debug mode and execute the code step by step. Then you can see how your code jumps.

Your first two methods are method definition. Nothing is being done there yet. Your third method is a method definition but it is being decorated. There your first prints are done. (Method isn't executed yet!) Even there not all print commands in your `run_only_between` is executed. Only the outer prints and a new decorated method is returned, etc. It's hard to put into words.

Comment: @Tin Nguyen Using debugger was one of the first thing which came into my mind, and this is why I have posted this question. Some of the "jumps" between code was totally unclear for me. If only someone could explain me call stack step by step, that wolud be amazing.

Comment: There are a lot of jumps I know. And I understand why each of these jumps happen. It'd be easier if you point out some jumps you don't understand and see when running in debug mode. I'll explain those specific jumps. But I won't explain all the jumps because that explanation will be too convoluted and confusing.

Comment: @TinNguyen I have uploaded debug execution order and added my questions, can You please take a look?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/hb7Ad91.png I don't know how to explain it more intuitive. You have an easier time understanding it if you only look at a single decorator.